# Creating and shaping data for 1D CNN

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a (244, 108) numpy array. It contains percentage change of close value of a trade for each minute in one day ie 108 values and like that for 244 days. Basically its a 1D vector. So in order to do 1D CNN how should I shape my data?

What i have done:

```
x.shape = (244, 108)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=2)
x.shape = (243, 108, 1)
y.shape = (243,)
```

Model:

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=108, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.act1 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.act2 = torch.nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.act3 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.act4 = torch.nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1, stride=1)


        self.linear_layers = nn.Linear(1, 1)


    # Defining the forward pass    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.act1(x)
        x = self.act2(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.act3(x)
        x = self.act4(x)
        x = self.linear_layers(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

If each day should be separate instance for convolution your data should have the shape `(248, 1, 108)`. This seems more reasonable.

If you want all your days and minutes to be a continuum for network to learn it should be of shape `(1, 1, 248*108)`.

Basically first dimension is `batch` (how many training samples), second is the number of channels or features of sample (only one in your case) and last is the number of timesteps.

### Edit

Your pooling layer should be `torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(1)`. You should also `reshape` output from this layer like this: `pooled.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)` before pushing it through `torch.nn.Linear` layer.