# Feeding a 1D vector to Pytorch CNN

Tags: pytorch, regression, conv-neural-network

How to feed a 1D vector to Pytorch CNN
Data is of the shape (244, 108). It contains percentage change of close value of a trade for each minute in one day ie 108 values and like that for 244 days. Basically its a 1D vector.

How to load this data to conv1d for regression. What will be the in_channel, out_channel and kernal_size?

Data:

```
x.shape = (243, 108)
y.shape = (243,)
```

Model (I tried):-

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.act1 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.act2 = torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(1)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.act3 = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.act4 = torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(1)


        self.linear_layers = nn.Linear(1, 1)


    # Defining the forward pass    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.act1(x)
        x = self.act2(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.act3(x)
        x = self.act4(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.linear_layers(x)
        return x
```

Comment: I'm not an expert either, but I think your `kernel_size=3` will give an error because you're using a 1D Conv.

Comment: @Seankala why would that be and what does it have to do with 1D convolution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating and shaping data for 1D CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782774/creating-and-shaping-data-for-1d-cnn)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, but

```
>>> import torch
>>> import torch.nn as nn
>>> class Net(nn.Module):
...     def __init__(self): 
...         super().__init__() 
...         self.layer1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1) 
...         self.act1 = nn.ReLU() 
...         self.act2 = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(output_size=1) 
...
...         self.layer2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1) 
...         self.act3 = nn.ReLU() 
...         self.act4 = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(output_size=1)
...
...         self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=1)
...
...     def forward(self, x): 
...         x = self.act2(self.act1(self.layer1(x))) 
...         x = self.act4(self.act3(self.layer2(x))) 
...         x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1) 
...         x = self.linear_layer(x) 
...         return x
>>> net = Net()
>>> output = net(x.view(x.shape[0], 1, -1))
```

This gives an output of shape `[244, 1]`. We reshape `x` because the input of PyTorch's convolutional layers typically requires you to specify how many channels your input is, and in this case it seems like you have 1 channel. Check out [the official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv1d) for more information.

Hope this helps.